# Array search using arrayjobx

Tags: arrays

I'm using the `arrayjobx` to store data in arrays, and I want to search through those arrays.

For example, I might have a list of names and places and I want to search through those names to find the index of a given name in that array.

```
\newarray\Names
\newarray\Places
\readarray{\Names}{Alice,Bob,Charles,Steve,George}
\readarray{\Places}{Alberta,Bangkok,China,Saarland,Georgia}
```

I want something like `\findindex` so that I can call the place associated to the person, e.g.

```
\Places(\findindex{\Names}{Bob})
```

should output `Bangkok`.

How might I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that `arrayjobx` is able to retrieve the index of an entry, without doing a loop over the whole array. Are you tied to `arrayjobx` or would you accept other solutions?

Comment: I'd accept other solutions. Is there a good alternative to arrayjobx here? I did eventually figure out how to do a loop through the whole array to find the index, which solved my problem, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want a property list, rather than two independent arrays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\addperson}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_luftbahn_person_place_plist { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\Place}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nn \g_luftbahn_person_place_plist { #1 }
 }

\prop_new:N \g_luftbahn_person_place_plist
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addperson{Alice}{Alberta}
\addperson{Bob}{Bangkok}
\addperson{Charles}{China}
\addperson{Steve}{Saarland}
\addperson{George}{Georgia}

\begin{document}

Bob lives in \Place{Bob}.

\end{document}
```

[image]